# Does the channel by itself have an affect on WiFi signal?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, signal

There is one WiFi access points in range of my room and it's mine. Using the WiFi Analyzer application for my Android phone, I've found that the entire channel range is wide open. currently, I'm using Channel 6. Would changing the channel have any impact on signal strength if there's no other WiFi access points around?

Answer (score 1):

It might if there are other devices in the same frequency range (like cordless phones).

Comment: How can I tell what frequencies are being used by other devices? Is there some kind of tool that detects all signals on all channels?

Comment: For wifi you can use http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider for everything else you would need a freq scanner, a local ham radio club could hook you up with that.

Comment: Don't know of any tool, the best way is to keep changing channels until you get the best signal.

Comment: +1 @Moab - since there are no other networks around, it shouldn't be too hard to just find a good channel.

Comment: Moab: There are 14 available channels. Running downstairs to my wireless router, changing the channel, then running around the house to check on signal strength would take a long time. I would like to make this short and simple.

Comment: @Thomas Owens - There's no reason  you can't change the channel from a laptop within the wifi range.

Comment: Really? I thought you had to have a wired connection to the router to change the signal...let me check on that...

Comment: And wow. I can change channels remotely. nice.

Comment: @Thomas Owens - It's normally configurable in the firmware to allow or disallow wireless connections to do administration.  If it's on you can do the admin stuff once the wifi is setup.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of devices that also transmit on the same band as wifi.

Check out [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference_at_2.4_GHz) for a list.

To quote a page on Cisco.com:

> Jupiter Research reports 67 percent of all residential Wi-Fi problems are linked to interfering devices, such as cordless phones, baby monitors, and microwave ovens.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not matter which channel you are on.

Channels 1 - 11 called the ISM band. They can be used freely.
Channels 12 and 13 can be used for indoor use only and at less than 1 watt
Channel 14 can only be used in Japan, and only for 802.11b transmission.

**To improve performance on 2.4ghz**
Turn off 802.11b mode
Turn on bluetooth coexistence mode

**On both 2.4ghz and 5ghz routers you can do the following to improve performance:**

Turn on features like frame bursting, or if there are no neighbors that will interfere, turn on channel bonding (sometimes called channel aggregation or  40mhz spectrum).

Things like wireless phones and microwaves which also run on the 2.4 ghz, cover the entire spectrum (all channels).

Comment: Can you site some sources about the channel information?